# Module not found error i have installed all modules

Tags: reactjs

facing the issue when write this npm start

```
S C:\Users\Muhammad Anas\Desktop\cloud\cloud> npm start  > si@0.1.0 start > react-scripts start  node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1050   throw err;   ^    requireStack: [     'C:\\Users\\Muhammad Anas\\Desktop\\cloud\\cloud\\node_modules\\finalhandler\\index.js',     'C:\\Users\\Muhammad Anas\\Deskt
```

I have tried

```
npm install
npm i parseurl
```

Comment: try to delete node_modules and package-lock.json and install again. (do not delete package.json)

Comment: Could you please include the whole error you're seeing? This one seems to be truncated. Make sure to use proper code formatting https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting